# Check constructor takes no parameters with getConstructor()

Tags: java, reflection

I need to check few things on a class and one of them is making sure that the constructor of this class takes no parameters and it's hinted to use `getConstructor()`

I've checked online but I'm having trouble understanding the way to do it.

Can you guys help me in any way ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```java
try {
      Constructor<?>[] ctors = MyClass.class.getConstructors();
      if (ctors.length == 0) {
        //no constructor returned means only implicit no arg constructor available
      }
      for (Constructor<?> c : ctors) {
        if (c.getParameterTypes().length == 0) {
          //explicit no arg constructor present 
        }
      }
    }
    catch (SecurityException e) {
      // TODO either LOG the exception or re-throw, but not both
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getParameterCount()` on constructor object.
Below is a generic method code that does the job you want:

```
private static boolean checkDefaultConstructor(Class<?> cl) {
  Constructor<?>[] cons = cl.getConstructors();
  boolean defaultConstructor = false;
  for (Constructor<?> con : cons) {
    if (con.getParameterCount() == 0)
      defaultConstructor = true;
  }
  return defaultConstructor;
}
```